# Named credentials are not able to see in profile

Tags: lightning-experience, namedcredentials

I need to add a named credential for one of the profile .But after i look into profile named credential access I can't see any available name credential in org at profile, I navigate Profile==>Named credential Access==>edit display as below. Do I need to enable access from somewhere
[image]

can someone help please?

Comment: What is the "Identity Type" for the created NamedCredential- Is it "per user" or "named principal" or "anonymous"? You should be able to add see it for adding on a profile basis if the type is "per user".

Comment: Hi Swetha,It's Named Principal.

Comment: When using [Named Principal](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_define.htm&type=5) this would be used across all users, not a per-user credential. That explains why you can’t assign this named credential to specific permission sets or profiles.

Comment: But i can see a error like "The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential" in lwc

Comment: @basu were you able to resolve this problem? Can you post an answer with a solution?

Comment: @Swetha does that cover the Anonymous use as well? I get 'We couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required permissions, or the external credential "Azure_AD" might not exist.' Error msg when trying to run a callout routine using the Dev console.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "named principal" then you must complete two steps to give your user access to Named Credentials. At the Permission Set or Profile level:

1. Add your External Credentials to "External Credential Principal Access".
2. Enable User External Credentials in "Object Settings".

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_permsets_profiles.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Grant "Read" access to "UserExternalCredential" sObject for your profile from  for which you are making the callout.

Profile-->yourProfile-->Object Settings-->UserExternalCredential-->Read